# Factory class throwing error PHP

Tags: php, singleton, database-connection

Im trying to make a factory class in order to initiate a database connection so that i only ever have one instance of the database.

For some reason the factory static method

> getInstance()

doesn't want to be called so the factory isn't being created and i cant for love of me see why it wont be called. Here is my bootstrap where im trying to call the getInstance function:

```
require_once('app_config.php');
require_once('autoloader.php');

//Create new instance of PSR-O autoloader and register classes being used.
$classLoader = new SplClassLoader('App', SITE_ROOT);
$classLoader->register();

$factory = new App\Core\connectionFactory();
$dbh = $factory::getInstance()->getConnection();

$route = new App\Core\router();

$route->setDefaultController(DEFAULT_CONTROLLER);
$route->setDefaultMethod(DEFAULT_METHOD);

$route->do_route();

$controller = $route->getController();
$method = $route->getMethod();
$arguments = $route->getArgs();

$controller = 'App\\Frontend\\Base\\' . $controller . 'Controller';
$method = strtolower($method).'Method';
$controller = new $controller($dbh);
$controller->$method();
```

And here is my factory class:

```
namespace App\Core;


class connectionFactory {
    private static $instance = NULL;
    private $db;

    public static function getInstance()

    {

        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    private function db_connect_details(){
        $m_rdbms = 'mysql';
        $m_host = 'localhost';
        $m_db_name = 'cvcms';
        $m_host_name = $m_rdbms . ':host=' . $m_host. ';dbname=' . $m_db_name;
        $m_uname = 'root';
        $m_pwd ='';

        $m_arr_db_connect_details['hostname'] = $m_host_name;
        $m_arr_db_connect_details['user_name'] = $m_uname;
        $m_arr_db_connect_details['user_pwd'] = $m_pwd;

        return $m_arr_db_connect_details;
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        $sets = $this->db_connect_details();

        $m_host_name = $sets['hostname'];
        $m_user_name = $sets['user_name'];
        $m_user_pwd = $sets['user_pwd'];

        if (!$this->db)
            $this->db = new \PDO($m_host_name, $m_user_name, $m_user_pwd);
        $this->db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

As you can see im instantiating a new connectionFactory class and then trying to call the getInstance() static function and then the getConnection function in order to store the connection into

> $dbh

But im getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method App\Core\connectionFactory::getInstance() in E:\Programs\xampp\htdocs\CVCMS\App\Core\bootstrap.php on line 20

**First Question**
Any ideas why im getting this error? 
Also any idea on where i can improve this code? Seems a little messy.

**Second question**
When i have fixed this error, whats the best way of passing this to my DAL model where i have all my query and fetch functions?

Thankyou very much

Comment: Factories are not static.

Comment: Just a thought, why do a getInstance when you can do `$factory->getConnection()`

Comment: @teresko, thanks for the input, i have been reading up on them a fair bit and ive seen everywhere that they are hence why i implemented it like this, copying the same structure as others i have seen, so i am interested in why you say this? thanks

Comment: @Ejay, In regards to adhering to the factory pattern i believe you have to first get an instance of the factory so that you dont create more than one instance of it, hence the getInstance() function and then you can use the same instance to connect to the database using the getConnection() function therefore only having one connection to the database

Comment: I'm unable to understand _this_ factory pattern implementation.  (I'm still new to it so might be time to educate myself :))

Comment: @Ejay, i know hwat you mean its taken me a while to understand it and i still dont think i do 100%, im using it based on the fact many people seem to think its better than using the singlton pattern to create a database connection!

Comment: Well .. fuak .. how to explain. What you have there is a singleton (an antipattern). And it looks like you tried to implement "factory method" (also an antipattern). What you should have don is created a simple factory instance. The whole description of the differences seems beyond the scope of this question. Maybe try [php chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php), I can **try** to explain some of it there.

Comment: @TomBurman I think there should be a private constructor that prevents the coder from creating an instance of the factory class. Then you should call the `getInstance` _statically_ instead of an instance on left side. Again, there seems to be no restrictions on calling `getConnection` on an instance of factory, hence creating multiple database connections. And I think you're aiming for a `singleton factory` instead of just `factory`. AFAIK vanilla factory is a class that creates different type of objects based on parameters passed to _create_ method. (i'm still learning so could be WRONG)

Answer (score 0):

Ok just a quick shot (too much code):
Seems like you are creating an instance of connectionFactory (Keyword "new"):

```
$factory = new App\Core\connectionFactory();
$dbh = $factory::getInstance()->getConnection();
```

Try:

```
$dbh = App\Core\connectionFactory::getInstance()->getConnection();
```

Comment: Unfortunately i Stillg et the Error Chris, thanks for the input though, any other ideas?